# UDP Holepunching Issue

Tags: c#, python, udp, hole-punching

So I wrote a simple python server to use for setting up P2P connections (for a game I'm making).

The server code is simple (python):

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = ''
server_port = 5000
server = (server_address, server_port)
sock.bind(server)
print("Listening on " + server_address + ":" + str(server_port))
while True:
    payload, client_address = sock.recvfrom(1)  
    resp = client_address[0] + ":" + str(client_address[1])
    print("Echoing data back to " + str(client_address))
    sent = sock.sendto(str.encode(resp), client_address)
```

It listens for incoming UDP messages and responds with the client's public **ip:port** info (eg '**xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa:port**').

The client receives this info from the server and updates their **ip:port** info on Firebase. All players in a firebase game lobby can see their opponents **ip:port** info.

However, the next part - P2P - doesn't work. 
Once the clients get their opponents public **ip:port** info and start sending UDP packets, none of them arrive.

Anyone know what the issue might be?

***** EDIT *****
I've solved the issue.. and it was not possible for anyone to answer based on the above info I gave. I was stupidly not renewing the port for receiving new udp packets after getting the first response from the server. Feeling pretty dumb atm. 
Anyways, the UDP holepunching system seems to be working.
My server is the python code above, and the client is a unity game (c#) with a firebase backend. If anyone has questions, please let me know.

Comment: Comment from @Dennis19901: Would you be so kind to share a code snippet of the UDP hole punching implemented? I'm planning to work on this myself soon enough, and it would save me quite a lot of research time!

Comment: @gofr1 - Which part are you interested in seeing? The server (python) code, or the C# P2P client code?

Comment: Thanks for feed back. I posted question from @Dennis19901, I hope he will come soon to clarify what he was asking about! :)

Comment: Thanks for notifying me @gofr1
I'm most interested in the P2P client code. How you setup the connections to the server first, and the other client second.
I'm guessing that the server only hands the remote IP from both clients to each other?

Comment: @Dennis19901- My setup is a bit confusing to lay out as it uses a firebase server and python (linux) server to set up the connections. Basically, the players are all in a game lobby (managed using firebase). Once the lobby is filled, they all ping the python server using empty UDP packets. The python server sees these clients public ip:port info coming in and responds with their own ip:port data as the message (see above). The players take the ip:port data (their own) from the python server response and then fill out the fields on the firebase game lobby.

Comment: @Dennis19901- Once the info is all added to firebase game lobby, the players now all start sending udp packets to each other using the ip:port info. This is when the hole punching happens. Once player A sends a packet to player B, it gets rejected. But then player B sends to player A and it will go through as player A's router opened a hole for player B after the first out message.

Please let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 1):

The listening ports would have to be open on the router. You need to go the extra step of adding a UPNP registration.

This is a library with no setup so no pip install https://github.com/jfdelgad/port-forward

This is a library you can pip install https://github.com/flyte/upnpclient

Both have excellent examples of their usage in the README.md

Comment: Thanks for the info! I will look into the UPnP docs and c# implementation (game is in c#). Although I was under the impression that UDP Holepunching can be done without any additional protocols.